What minimum linux's root partition size for virtual machine
I wanna install multiple linux distro (Ubuntu, Fedora, Manjaro, Opensusue, etc) via virtual machine (qemu) with shared /home partition for testing purposes, which i'm not gonna install anything big or lot of thing inside root partition.
What is the minimum size or recommended size of root partition of each linux distro for this type of usage?

Most distributions will specify a minimum and recommended size; its different for each one and also depends on how you configure it, but the install may temporarily require more storage. Use the recommendations as a starting point and test if a smaller volume works

If you use the QCOW2 format for your virtual disks you will not need to worry too much about the size. QCOW2 files start small and grow as data is written to them, only using as much physical storage as needed.
qemu-img create -f qcow2 mydisk.qcow2 10G
The above command will create a virtual disk that can grow to 10G but will be of minimal size initially

....but you need to use fstrim or mount with discard to recover space from deleted files.

The smallest size of / filesystem is between 1GB and 2.5GB. But some installers (RH for example) may require more, 10GB, to start the installation process.


What is the minimum size or recommended size of root partition of each linux distro for this type of usage?

You will need to check with each individual distro because they have quite different requirements. They also have various installation "sets", e.g. Fedora offers "Minimal Install" which needs less than 2GB but if you choose e.g. ""Fedora Workstation" (based on Gnome), you'll need at least 4GB:

If you're going to install any desktop software, e.g. a desktop environment and web browsers, you should target at least 4GB. Firefox 126 along takes over 250MB. Google Chrome comes in at over 330MB.
